# There is how to change workspace only of the primary monitor?

Tags: screen, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I've two screens and I'm using Unity Interface. In GNOME shell we're able to change the workspace of just the primary, what make sense for me. How  can I do that on the Unity?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have an actual answer to your question, I do have a work-around which I have been using to get your described behaviour.

If you right click on a window titlebar, you'll get multiple options and amongst those there should be one saying something like "Always visible on workspace". This will make the window appearing on all workspaces.

Comment: was not a solution but a nice workaround!

Comment: good idea thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could replicate this behavior and add more features with gnome-tweak-tool. You can install it using:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Below I let you an image with my Tweak set up to replicate your expected behavior

(Image as Link cause reputation :/)

[My Tweaks Workspaces config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iefml.png)